# How to save the JavaScript runtime state

Tags: javascript, runtime, persistence, distributed

I want to be able to take a snapshot of a running javascript program, save it to a database, wait for some period of time, load back the state and continue the process execution. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, you can write the code to capture that "snapshot", the code to save and retrieve it from the database, and the code to load the data to the DOM.

Comment: You mean a "save state" or something akin to that?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to describe saving the memory/CPU state, such as with a VM, and load that state later.  Are you *sure* this is what you're looking to do?  Or are you just trying to save some data somewhere and retrieve that data when the page loads?

Comment: AFAIK there's nothing built-in that does this. You should just save the variables relevant to your application in a JSON file or `localStorage`, and reload them when you want to restart.

Comment: Look in to DevTools Memory. Technically you can log the line of the code to determine where you are in the execution state. The requirement should be possible. It's just like calling `chrome` at the command line. You get to see everything that's going on that is printed. You can redirect that data to a separate file, similar to netlog for `chrome`, or any other program you can pipe output to a file from.

Comment: @David I am working on my pet project - a workflow engine like airflow (a system that executes arbitrary tasks described as functions). The tasks that the described system can run are limited to the short-running ones because it is too expensive and not reliable to maintain everlasting functions. So, I was wondering if it would be possible to "snapshot" such processes, move them to a persistent storage, and then load back when some event occurs. Also, snapshotting is crucial for load balancing (moving processes between machines)

Comment: I picked javascript because it is popular and a type of language that, in my opinion, might have the described functionality.